# How do i use Sqoop to save data in a parquet-avro file format?

Tags: hadoop, avro, parquet, sqoop

I need to move my data from a relational database to HDFS but i would like to save the data to a [parquet-avro](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-avro) file format. Looking at the [sqoop documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html) it seems like my options are --as-parquetfile or --as-avrodatafile, but not a mix of both. From my understanding of this [blog](http://grepalex.com/2014/05/13/parquet-file-format-and-object-model/)/picture below, the way parquet-avro works is that it is a parquet file with the avro schema embedded and a converter to convert and save an avro object to a parquet file and vise versa.

My initial assumption is that if i use the sqoop option --as-parquetfile then the data being saved to the parquet file will be missing the avro schema and the converter won't work. However upon looking at the [sqoop code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/7c1754270ff21f533088b946c873321f890da791/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/mapreduce/ParquetImportMapper.java#L68) that saves the data to a parquet file format it does seem to be using a util related to avro but i'm not sure what's going on. Could someone clarify? If i cannot do this with sqoop, what other options do i have?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`parquet-avro` is mainly a convenience layer so that you can read/write data that is stored in Apache Parquet into Avro object. When you read the Parquet again with `parquet-avro`, the Avro schema is inferred from the Parquet schema (alternatively you should be able to specify an explicit Avro schema). Thus you should be fine with `--as-parquetfile`.